# quartz2d translating the origin

Tags: objective-c, ipad, quartz-graphics, scale, translate

My understanding of quartz2d is that the code `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y);` translates the coordinate system.  I have a quartz2d view with lots of shapes on it, and the user needs to be able to pan around and zoom it.  However, when using the `CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleX, scaleY);` code, everything scales around the origin, not the center of the viewpoint the user is viewing.

My solution to this was to use the following code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 512.0+offset.x, 384.0+offset.y);  
//(512, 384) is the center of the iPad screen
CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
```

You can translate around fine, but things still scale into the corner.  What's wrong?

EDIT: Oh. Wow. Duh.  If you move the origin, the shapes move too, so you can't move it relative to the shapes.  Now I know what's wrong, but how do I do that?(move the origin independently of the shapes)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much experience with using the CoreGraphics C API, but have you considered sticking your view onto a UISCrollView? If the functionality is there and its free, why not use it?

Comment: Hmmm,I never thought of that.  I have solved the problem, though.  I ended up translating manually all the shapes in the view and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UIView class for each shape.
The instantiate an UIView object for each shape to move arround.

Then you change the center of tht view objects with shape.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
Probably the method is calls bounds.center, look in UIView.

This will automatically call drawRect() and all is fine!